# Laravel Eloquent how to create relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have four tables.

- User (user_id)
- Orders (order_id & user_id)
- Order_detail (post_id, order_id, product_id)
- Product (comment_id)

How to create relationship between user table and product table? I have managed to create relationships between the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function orderDetails() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail');
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}

class OrderDetail extends Model
{
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Orders');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in User model:

```
use App\Models\Product; \\or your Product model path
class User extends Authenticatable{

public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
}
```

and in Product model:

```
use App\Models\User; \\or your User model path

class Product extends Model{

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```